# What is the Fourier transform of this expression in $2\omega$ dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, integration, regularization, dimensional-regularization

I would like to perform the following Fourier transform in $2\omega$ (Euclidean) dimensions:

$$A(x_1,q) = \int d^{2\omega} p_1\ e^{i p_1 \cdot x_1} \frac{\delta^{(1)}(v \cdot (p_1 + q))}{p_1^2 (p_1^2 + q^2)^{\omega-3/2}}$$

with $v:=(0,0,0,1)$, $x_1:=(1,0,0,0)$ and $q$ an arbitrary $4$-vector when $\omega\to 2$. I can't make sense of this expression in $2\omega$ dimensions though. Is it divergent in this case? If yes, is it possible to do the integral and to expand in $\epsilon$?